# use of “to” in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "to" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If not, could you please suggest some words to replace "to"?

> Particular care has been devoted **to** construct a high quality mesh,
>   especially at tip clearance zone.

Answer (score 4):

Nearly, but not quite. The "to" is right, but not what follows.

The verb "devoted" needs to take as its object 'to' + a noun phrase, so

> devoted to construct**ing** ...

or

> devoted to construct**ion of** ...

With a different verb, that doesn't need a "to" object, such as "take care", your form would work:

> Particular care has been taken to construct ...

because "take care" can take a "to infinitive" as its object. But "devote" requires 'to' plus a noun phrase. There's no explanation for this difference: it just happens to be how English works.

Comment: Isn't an article needed in: *...devoted to **the** construction of...* No?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I think it's optional. If you were talking about constructing something in general, rather than a specific instance, you wouldn't want it. Here you could have it, but I don't think it's essential.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It is absolutely correct.

> *Devote* has a meaning of "to give up or appropriate to or concentrate on a particular pursuit, occupation, purpose, cause, etc."

So it's actually:

> Particular care has been concentrated on the construction of a high
>   quality mesh, especially at tip clearance zone.